# Insert sentence to DB

Tags: c#

I'm working on ASP- and I have build in DB and I want to know how to write a code for insert sentences. on C#???

Comment: Not 100% clear what you're asking but how about this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: which DB? ms sql! did you use entity frame work?

Comment: sql DB - the build in one in ASP project

Comment: this is how i read data:

Comment: public TblConstant getParameter(int parameterId)
        {

            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var DBParameter = from param in db.TblConstants
                              where param.code == parameterId
                              select param;
            return DBParameter.Single();
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your comment .
You are using entity framework. and the table called TblConstants.

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
TblConstant tb = new TblConstant();
tb.Field1 = Value1;
tb.Field2 = Value2;
...
db.AddToTblConstants(tb);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanx- it seems better- what is db.? i don't find it in my project

Comment: i wrote this:public TblLine insertParameter(string name, string id)
{
    TblLine tl = new TblLine();
    tl.persomName = name;
    tl.personId = id;

Comment: db is your datacontecontext. I got it from your comment DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

Comment: i'm sorry i'm so bad- i'm new in it - when i write datacontecontext- it doesn't has AddToTblConstant in it's properties

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are working with ASP.NET, if so you can use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanx- but i can't find there an example in C# for insert query (data to DB)

Answer (score 0):

Still something is missing. Whether do you want to insert ACCESS / SQL / MySQL database? If you are looking for Access then [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=vs.71).aspx) will really help you.

For MS-SQL database, you can do like following:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your connection string"))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("your insert query");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: it is sql, but build in in my ASP project , i don'd need to open connection- just to insert data!   i have object for each table

Answer (score 0):

C# can't directly insert records into a database.  Ultimately you need to execute SQL on the database (as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).  There are various C# frameworks and wrappers that enable execution of SQL statements in a database, at different levels of abstraction.

Most directly you can use ADO.NET which allows you to open connections to a database and execute SQL directly.

You could use LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework.  These allow you work with a database as if it was a collection of C# objects.  However you first need to set up mappings from you database schema to the C# classes you wish to use.  LINQ to SQL supports direct 1-1 mappings between tables and classes, Entity Framework supports much more complex mappings.

You could use non-Microsoft frameworks such as N-hibernate. This has (as far as I know) a similar feature set to Entity Framework.